# use tinyMCE with VUEJS 2 without apikey

Tags: vue.js, tinymce

I would like to use TinyMCE locally and avoid having to provide an API Key. For the moment I use the following code:

Install TinyMCE for vueJS 2.x:

```
npm install --save "@tinymce/tinymce-vue@^3"
```

When installed, I use this:

```html
 <template>
   <div id="app">
     <img alt="Vue logo" src="./assets/logo.png">
     <editor
       api-key="no-api-key"
       :init="{
         height: 500,
         menubar: false,
         plugins: [
           'advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor',
           'searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen',
           'insertdatetime media table paste code help wordcount'
         ],
         toolbar:
           'undo redo | formatselect | bold italic backcolor | \
           alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | \
           bullist numlist outdent indent | removeformat | help'
       }"
     />
   </div>
 </template>

 <script>
 import Editor from '@tinymce/tinymce-vue'

 export default {
   name: 'app',
   components: {
     'editor': Editor
   }
 }
 </script>
```

Comment: Looks like the documentation says it's fine to use tinymce without an apikey, you'll just get a notice https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/quick-start/#step3addyourapikey What would be an answer that satisfies you? Should it show how to hide the notice? I'm not sure about what's wrong with the code you've posted above

Comment: @walnut_salami> goal is to avoid having a notice...

Answer (score 0):

The TinyMCE Vue wrapper will rely on our Cloud platform to pull TinyMCE if TinyMCE is not already loaded into the page/application.

The simplest approach is the self host TinyMCE and place a script tag in the head of the main HTML page to load TinyMCE.  This will make the tinymce global object available at all times in all components.  Alternatively you can import TinyMCE in the component(s) that need it.  As long at the tinymce global is there before you try to create an editor component there will be no attempt to use the Cloud delivered version of TinyMCE.

Step 6 of the quick start guide covers this specific capability:

https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/integrations/vue/#tinymcevuejsintegrationquickstartguide

Comment: thanks I will try this today and keep you posted.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work. Can you give an example that works ?